# Kotlin корутины, обеспечить завершение предыдущей перед запуском следующей

Tags: javafx, kotlin, coroutine

Пишу приложение на связке kotlin (с корутинами) и JavaFX. (в целях изучения)

Соответственно есть поле ввода `search` с листенером на изменение, который по мере набора текста дергает такой код:

```
launch(UI) {
    progressIndicator.isVisible=true
    result.text = search(search.text) //медленный запрос
    progressIndicator.isVisible=false
}
```

Соответственно, если набирать текст быстро, то стартует несколько корутин, что не очень здорово само по себе, да еще и `progressIndicator.isVisible` начинает хаотично становиться то `true`, то `false`.

Каким образом можно организовать так, что при каждом запуске корутины проверялось, не запущена ли она уже, убивалась старая и выполнялся подчищающий код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем то, чего хотелось, но за неимением других решений...

Объявляем свойство объекта

```
var lastRun = Date().time
```

Метод с корутиной

```
val current = Date().time
lastRun = current
progressIndicator.isVisible=true
launch(UI) {
    delay(500)  //задержка ввода
    if(lastRun > current) return@launch
    val searchResult = search(search.text) //медленный запрос
    if(lastRun > current) return@launch
    result.text = searchResult
    progressIndicator.isVisible=false
}
```

Comment: А зачем перезапускать корутину, не будет ли эффективней создать для нее очередь заданий и смотреть есть ли еще что сделать? Если нет, то выход. А запускать при появлении первого задания.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Вы предлагаете запускать ее в вечном цикле? Плюс все равно придется накручивать логику с очередью. Не уверен, что это будет лучше

Comment: Не в вечном, в "умном" цикле. А логика будет не сложнее, чем сейчас с `lastRun` + `current`

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja если не в вечном, то в листенер на изменение придется прикручивать логику, определяющую, запущена ли корутина или нет, для определения, надо ли ее запускать или достаточно в очередь докинуть. В целом не вижу никаких плюсов