# Как дождаться окончания корутины

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

Я только начал изучать котлин и корутины, так что прошу сильно не ругаться за глупый вопрос.

Надо дождаться окончания выполнение кода в корутине и потом получить значение функции, выполненной в корутине и включить кнопку. Функция test() выполняется в корутине что бы не подвисала программа, пока выполняется цикл.

Есть такой код:

```
suspend fun test(): String {
    delay(5000) // типа долгий цикл
    return "трали-вали" // строка полкченная полсе выполнения цикла
}

fun onClick(view: View) {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        val result: String = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
            test()
            btnStart.isEnabled = true // не работает :(
        }
    }
    var strokaIsCikla = result // не работает :(
}
```

как дождаться окончания корутины и включить кнопку?

как дождаться окончание корутины и получить из нее значение  функции в переменную ( result)?

Понимаю что вопросы совсем глупые, но сам дотумкать не могу.

---

Вообще код выглядит так:

```
private var flag = false

private fun test(): String {
    var s: Long = 0
    while (s < 100000 && flag) { //  долгий цикл, зависит от вводимых данных
        s += 1
    }
    return "$s" // строка полученная после выполнения цикла
}


fun btnStartClick(view: View) {
    btnStart.isEnabled=false
    flag = true
    println(test())
    btnStart.isEnabled = true
}


fun btnStopClick(view: View) {
    flag = false
}
```

но во время цикла прога как бы зависает и это выглядит не очень эстетично.
Я подумал что можно цикл вынести в корутину что избкжать подвисания.
Но возможно есть другой вариант. Хочется избежать подвисания программы во время выполнения цикла. Что бы, например, была возможность нажать btnStop и остановить цикл. Но в моем коде во время цикла все висит и в том числе все View.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса? [Kotlin корутины, обеспечить завершение предыдущей перед запуском следующей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/712920/kotlin-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9)

Comment: Переменная strokaIsCikla хатит получить значение функции выполненой в корутине, но у нее не получается. И у меня тоже :(

Comment: Смотрите, у вам `result` определен в блоке `GlobalScope.launch {` - это значит. что он только в этом блоке и будет работать, за блоком работать не будет. Вам нужно выше блока сделать инициализацию `val result: String =""`, а уже в блоке `res =withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {`, но увы, код ждать не будет, по этому перед `var strokaIsCikla = result`, нужно добавить  `Thread.sleep(6000L)`, чтобы подождать и записать переменную `strokaIsCikla`.

Comment: Смотроите в сторону [scheduleAtFixedRate](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/java.util.-timer/schedule-at-fixed-rate.html) или [schedule](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/java.util.-timer/schedule.html), но опять-же, я не знаю, что вы там пытаетесь сотворить, добавьте подробности в свой вопрос и больше кода, я не понимаю к примеру, что вы тут делаете. Сделаейте минимально рабочий пример тут или где-то на плайгроунде у самого же котлина, чтобы было понятно, что у вас за проблема.

Comment: Я поэтому и пытаюсь сделать это через поток, точнее через корутины. Но как потом получить значение переменной или функции из потока  ? И как можно ждать окончание выполнения потока что бы выполнить isEnabled=true только после того как закончится цикл в потоке?  Информации на эту тему много но с каждым обновлением в корутинах что то меняют, и сейчас почти все примеры по корутинам не работают, так как часть функций убрали, а часть заменили на что то другое.

Comment: Вы, видимо не понимаете, как работает корутина, суть такая, она выполняется, а код, что ниже ждать ее не будет. А о том, что у вас в самом блоке не работает присвоение переменной, вы ошибаетесь, на самом деле, код где эта переменная используется просто не ждет никак корутину, по этому, вы этого не видите. По этому пока корутина выполняется, код, который до и после, уже давным давно выполнился, вот и все.

Answer (score 0):

GlobalScope.launch нельзя так использовать, данный механизм предназначен для выполнения отложенных задач, то есть как только вы описали что должно происходить в блоке GlobalScope.launch далеко не факт что он будет выполняться сразу, если нужно чтобы корутина возвращала результат используйте GlobalScope.async, но как понял вам нужно чтобы чтобы после выполнения какой либо задачи кнопка стала доступной, можно попробовать так

```
fun btnStartClick(view: View) {
    btnStart.isEnabled = false
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        flag = true
        println(test())
        btnStart.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

Dispatchers.Main - имеется ввиду что корутина будет выполняться в главном UI потоке, но не будет его блокировать.

Comment: GlobalScope вообще не рекомендуется к использованию. Мы не можем контроллировать его. Лучше создавать свои скоупы